# MongoDB object isn't deleted from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to delete something from my mongoDb database based on the _id. In my console I keep getting the message that the row was deleting but when I check the database, the object still exists.

this is my function :

```
     function deleteById(){
//5989df87e027c737e5500d17
url_database=  mongodb://localhost:27017/incept

MongoClient.connect(url_database, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var myquery = { _id: '5989df87e027c737e5500d17' };
    db.collection("medicament").removeOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
        if (err){
            console.log("failed");
            throw err;
        }
            console.log("1 document deleted");
        db.close();
    });
});
}
```

This is my json object

```
    { _id: 5989df87e027c737e5500d17,
      medicine_name: 'ada',
      dosage_value: 'ads',
      dosage_unit: 'MG',
      prescribed_for_days: 'ads',
      doctor_name: 'asda',
      morning_select: '06:00',
      afternoon_select: '06:00',
      evening_select: '06:00',
      night_selct: '06:00' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your string `_id` value into an `ObjectID` as that's how it's stored in the collection:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

var myquery = { _id: mongodb.ObjectID('5989df87e027c737e5500d17') };
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the method removeOne. I think to delete you have to use deleteOne.

[deleteOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/)

Comment: Or just use 'remove'

Comment: It appears that `removeOne` is an alias for `deleteOne` in the driver so either works.

Comment: In NodeJS removeOne is part of [UnorderedBulkOperation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/unordered.html#removeone). If you want to remove the data from collection you can use `deleteMany`, `deleteOne` or `db.collectionName.remove`.
[removeone](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/FindOperatorsUnordered.html#removeOne)

`removeOne` can be used in case of bulk operations.